# I'm trying to run an oracle database in virtual box under oracle linux

Tags: linux, oracle

I'm trying to run a oracle DB in VirtualBox and access it from my host mac OSX , i am using port forwarding to access my guest, I can telnet my guest on the port, however when i try to connect from SQL developer i get IO error got minus one from a read call.

have googled around, one potential gotcha was specific ips allowed in the sqlnet.ora config - not the problem,  any idea this is really annoying me now

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using? Have you started the listener? Is the firewall (iptables, most likely) active?

Comment: hi I'm using oracle linux - have disabled firewalls, is it best to enable and add my ip to it?

Comment: If you can telnet over the port then it should work. Can you give us the actual error message please?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Turned out to be a firewall issue. Here is how I turned it off:

As root in terminal:
chkconfig iptables off
chkconfig ip6tables off
service iptables stop
service ip6tables stop

Then modify /etc/selinux/config and set SELINUX=enforcing to SELINUX=disabled.

A more elegant solution is to open the 1521 port in the firewall. You can do that in the System -> Administration -> Firewall menu. Add 1521 (tcp) under "Other ports".

Comment: Not only a link but a youtube video? It would be more helpful if you added the steps you did here, not in a link that may stop working tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will edit.